# My device is authorized but after I run login test it says to authorize it again -QA Tester

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, automation, webdriver

I’m literally a newbie in this domain and I am using java + selenium to create tests. The website I’m testing has a one-time step per device and browser and when I run the Login Test it always gets to the point where i need to authorize the device and browser again and again. When I try to login manually I don’t have this problem, also my collague doesn’t seem to have this problem. Help ? I used chrome and firefox and they both have the same problem.

```
package confidential;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class PositiveTests
{
    @Test

    public void loginTest()
    {
        System.out.println("Starting loginTest");

        //Create driver

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\EcaterinaComardicea\\IdeaProjects\\seleniumforbeginnerss\\src\\main\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        //sleep for 1 second
        //sleep(1000);

        //maximize browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //open test page
        String url = "confidential";
        driver.get(url);
        System.out.println("Page is opened");

        //sleep for 2 seconds
        sleep(2000);

        //enter username
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        username.sendKeys("confidential");
        sleep(1000);

        //enter password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        password.sendKeys("confidential");
        sleep(3000);

        //click login button
        WebElement logInButton = driver.findElement(By.id("btn_signin"));
        logInButton.click();
        sleep(5000);



    }

    private void sleep(long m) {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(m);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to do this?

Comment: hi, i updated my post and added the code. I hid the confidential stuff though, hope it helps

Comment: This looks pretty standard. Not sure why you're seeing this issue, as I've never seen it before -- my only guess is something may be happening to your cookies.  This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504038/selenium-test-runs-wont-save-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running the same test for facebook and apparently the proxy was the problem. 
I set my firefox to "No proxy" from settings and now it works as it should. I hope this was it.

Thank you all for your help and suggestions, you are awesome people !

Answer (score 0):

Ecaterina, this is expected. When you login to some website which require authorization, its checking if u logged in to this website before from this browser, by checking your cookies and authorization token, if it's there its gonna skip authorization step. But when u running Selenium test, every time when it's open new browser instance everything cleared. So it's doesn't recognize this browser.